# How to save LLVM DEBUG into a file

Tags: debugging, gdb, llvm, llvm-c++-api

Hello, I'm studying on LLVM register allocation.

In order to understand the compilation flow, I tried to save DEBUG infos into a file but failed.

Since the application I'm running is in python, I tried as the followings:

```
gdb python
b Debug.cpp:43 -> Where DebugFlag = false resides
run test.py
set DebugFlag = 1
continue
```

I tried redirecting (run test.py > tmp.txt) and "set logging on" in gdb, but still doesn't show the information of DEBUG.

Can anyone give me an advice for saving DEBUG information of LLVM?

Regards,

Jake

Comment: Oh, the Deubug.cpp is in LLVM source code.

Comment: OK, from what I can tell, any debug information from the LLVM library should go to stderr. That will be your terminal, by default. Are you seeing that info when you run test.py, after you set DebugFlag and continue the program?

Comment: The info comes after I set the DebugFlag. Like you said, I managed to print the debug info by splitting the process: I first generated test.ll file and then put it in shell script (llc test.ll -debug), and then printed the shell script as ./run.sh &> out . This worked. However, I tried putting the codes I wrote above into shell script and do the same redirection but seems like not working.